# Problem while upgrading simplenews

Tags: 7, emails

I am a newbie in Drupal. I recently upgraded a site from D6 to D7. The site used simplenews module. So i got the D7 equivalent and installed it. After enabling the module i find the following issues -

1) The newsletter page does not display the subscription area any more. Earlier the newsletter page asked the user to fill in the name and email and subscribe/unsubscribe radio boxes and a save button. When i am logged in as admin i only get the username and a unsubscribe button.

2) When i compare the simplenews folder then i find out that the earlier version has a simplenews_action folder which I dont have in my D7 version.

3) The site previously also used the simplenews_realname module which helped to retrieve names and emails of individuals if an export option was tried. What should i do for this since I could not find a simplenews_realname version for D7.

4) I opened EDIT for the newsletter page to find out the following for the simplenews code.

```
<p class="content"><!--?php $block = module_invoke('simplenews','block','view',27); print $block['content']; ?--></p>
```

so i changed it to this -

```
<p class="content"><?php $block = module_invoke('simplenews','block_view',27); print render($block['content']); ?></p>
```

But this also didn't solve the purpose. How can i fix this simplenews problem. Any sort of help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Now i tried commenting out this php code in the page and tried to add a block for simplenews. Configuration > Web Services > Newsletters > Edit newsletter category. Here i checked the Subscription Block. Now when i go to Structure > Blocks, i see the newsletter block there under disabled. I configure it and check the subscription form radio button and give the page where i want it to be displayed. Still no show.... :(